# What is the difference between using Glassfish Server -> Local and Remote

Tags: configuration, glassfish, intellij-idea, webserver

I am using Intellij IDEA to develop my applications and I use glassfish for my applications.

When I want to run/debug my application I can configure it from `Glassfish Server -> Local` and define arguments at there. However there is another section instead of Glassfish Server, there is a `Remote` section for configuration. I can easily configure and debug my application just defining host and port variables.

So my question is why to need for Glassfish Server Local configuration(except for when defining extra parameters) and what is difference between them(I mean performance or etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local starts Glassfish for you and performs the deployment. With Remote you start Glassfish manually. Remote can be used to debug apps running on another machines, Local is useful for development and testing.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of development work-flow optimizations and automation that can be performed by an IDE when it is working with a local server.  I don't have a strong background in IDEA, so I am not sure which of the following they may have implemented:

1. using in-place|exploded|directory deployment can eliminate jar/war/ear creation in the IDE and deconstruction in the server.  This can be a significant time saver.
2. linked to 1 is smarter redeployment.  In some cases, a file change (like changing a jsp or an html file) does not need to trigger redeployment.
3. JDBC driver integration allows users to configure their IDE to access a DB and then propagates that configuration (which usually includes driver jars, etc.) into the server's classpath as part of deployment of an app.
4. access to server log files during deployment and execution.
5. The ability to start and stop the server... even today, you do need to restart GlassFish sometimes.
6. view the generated Java sources of a JSP.

Most of these features are not available with a remote server and that has a negative effect on iterative development since the break between edit and validate can be fairly long.

This answer is based on my familiarity with the work that we have done for the NetBeans/GlassFish integration.  The guys at IntelliJ are smart, so I would not be surprised if they have other features that are available when you are working with a local server.